# using shared preferences in android to fill data in forms

Tags: android

I am developing an android Application for managing and creating personal and business cards.
How can I use Shared Preferences  (where i will be storing my personal and professional information ) in creating the cards. 
Every time i need to create a new card, the program should ask me to gather information from the Shared Preferences and also my "create new Card" form should ask for adding new fields (like another or new e-mail not present in shared preferences ) dynamically.

please let me know any sample examples explaining such scenario..... I have extensively searched over internet to find some, but couldn't get any as per my requirement.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement it should be better to use [`sqlite database`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html). because if you are adding more records then it always better to use database for storing similar type of data..

otherwise if you want to use Shared Preference only then try like this...

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
//Storing data
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("pref_empId", _empid);
edit.putString("pref_userName", _username);
edit.putString("pref_userType", _usertype);
edit.commit();

//Retrieving 
pref_userName = preferences.getString("pref_userName", "n/a");
pref_empId =  preferences.getString("pref_empId","n/a");
pref_userType =  preferences.getString("pref_userType","n/a");
```

Comment: hi, thankyou for your prompt reply, can you please help me figure out how to execute the sample code from https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu and also use the same for my other projects?

Answer (score 0):

In shared preferences you can store the info as key-value pair. For details read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref